# How to convert List<List<Map<String, String>>> into List<List<CustomObject>> in dart

Tags: dart

I want to convert a List<List<Map<String, String>>> into List<List> a custom class, how to achieve this in dart.

How to convert this

```
List<List<Map<String, String>>> = [
      {
        "course_name": "Estimation & Quantity Surveying",
        "credit": "4",
        "hours": "40",
      },
      {
        "course_name": "IDP - Industrial Design Project phase II",
        "credit": "4",
        "hours": "40",
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "course_name": "Data Base Management System",
        "credit": "4",
        "hours": "40",
      },
      {
        "course_name": "Estimation & Quantity Surveying",
        "credit": "4",
        "hours": "40",
      },
    ],
  ];
```

into

```
List<List<StudentTimeTable>>
```

This is my custom class

```
class StudentTimeTable{
  final String courseName;
  final String credit;
  final String hours;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
class StudentTimeTable {
  final String courseName;
  final String credit;
  final String hours;

  StudentTimeTable.fromMap(Map<String, String> map)
      : courseName = map['course_name'],
        credit = map['credit'],
        hours = map['hours'];

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'StudentTimeTable(courseName = $courseName, credit = $credit, hours = $hours)';
}

void main() {
  List<List<Map<String, String>>> input = [
    [
      {
        "course_name": "Estimation & Quantity Surveying",
        "credit": "4",
        "hours": "40",
      },
      {
        "course_name": "IDP - Industrial Design Project phase II",
        "credit": "4",
        "hours": "40",
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "course_name": "Data Base Management System",
        "credit": "4",
        "hours": "40",
      },
      {
        "course_name": "Estimation & Quantity Surveying",
        "credit": "4",
        "hours": "40",
      },
    ],
  ];

  List<List<StudentTimeTable>> output = [
    ...input.map(
        (subList) => [...subList.map((map) => StudentTimeTable.fromMap(map))])
  ];

  output.forEach(print);
  // [StudentTimeTable(courseName = Estimation & Quantity Surveying, credit = 4, hours = 40), StudentTimeTable(courseName = IDP - Industrial Design Project phase II, credit = 4, hours = 40)]
  // [StudentTimeTable(courseName = Data Base Management System, credit = 4, hours = 40), StudentTimeTable(courseName = Estimation & Quantity Surveying, credit = 4, hours = 40)]
}
```

#### Explanation of what going on!

The solution makes use of "spread operator" which you can read more about here:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator

In shot, it is a easy way to create a new list and take all elements in an iterable and put into the list.

So lets see what I do:

```
List<List<StudentTimeTable>> output = [...input.map((subList) => ...)]
```

Here we define a new list which are filled with the elements from `input.map`. The `map` method are used to take each element in the `input` and convert it to something else. In our case we want to convert each element in our input (which are also a `List`) from `List<Map<String, String>>` to `List<StudentTimeTable>`

We are then mapping each `List<Map<String, String>>` to the value from this:

```
[...subList.map((map) => StudentTimeTable.fromMap(map))]
```

Which returns a list filled with the elements from the iterator returned from `subList.map`. The purpose of this `map` is to convert `Map<String, String>` into `StudentTimeTable`.

This is done by calling our new constructor which takes a `Map<String, String>`:

```
  StudentTimeTable.fromMap(Map<String, String> map)
      : courseName = map['course_name'],
        credit = map['credit'],
        hours = map['hours'];
```

The same code could have been written something like this which is properly easier to read:

```
  final output = <List<StudentTimeTable>>[];

  for (final sublist in input) {
    final studentTimeTableSubList = <StudentTimeTable>[];

    for (final map in sublist) {
      studentTimeTableSubList.add(StudentTimeTable.fromMap(map));
    }

    output.add(studentTimeTableSubList);
  }
```

And a third way would be something like this which uses "collection for" from the same link about "spread operator":

```
  final output = [
    for (final sublist in input)
      [for (final map in sublist) StudentTimeTable.fromMap(map)]
  ];
```

Comment: I need the output only in List<List<StudentTimeTable>>, will this help me to achieve this.

Comment: Output is already that type. I just used the foreach for easier print.

Comment: Thankyou my friend, This is really a magic and this works fine. Could you explain me how this works?

Comment: Added some explanation.

Comment: Now how to save and get this List<List<StudentTimeTable>> using shared preference?

Comment: That would be a new question ;) (also, I don't know since I am not a Flutter developer)